# Install libmysqlclient 5.5.3 on Centos 6

Tags: centos, mysql, php

I'm installing Drupal 8 on my Centos 6 server. To do this I needed to upgrade both PHP and MySQL. However, I'm now getting the following error message:

> The libmysqlclient driver version 5.1.54 is less than the minimum
>   required version. Upgrade to libmysqlclient version 5.5.3 or up, or
>   alternatively switch mysql drivers to MySQLnd version 5.0.9 or up.

How to upgrade the version of libmysqlclient as required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem, here's the solution I found.

The drupal-mysql package seems to use the 5.1 library, and I can't find any to override this.

However, switching to the drupal-mysqlnd package seems to resolve this.

In my case, the install command was:

```
yum install php56w-mysqlnd
```

Hope someone finds this useful.

James